# How to add CSS to a dynamic table created with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic-tables

Basically I'm creating a dynamic table on javascript and displaying it in the html page. I also have a css file that works on static elements, but not on the table i'm creating dynamically. what can I do to style my dynamically created table?

I've tried this: `table.classList.add('tablestyle');` but it doesn't work.

As you can imagne, I'm absolutly new to this kind of things.

I have 3 files:

reports.component.ts  (that contains html. references to sccs & js are in the file and they work correctly)

```
<html>
<div class="block">
        <h1>STORICO DEI DATI</h1>
            <div id="myDynamicTable" class="table">
                <body onload="Javascript:addTable()"></body>
            </div>
        </div>
</html>
```

reports.component.js

```
function addTable() {

    let colonne = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)+2;  
    let righe = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)+2;  
    
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    
    today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
    
    let providers = ["p1", "p2", "p3", "np4", "p5"];
    let testcases = ["tc1", "tc2", "tc3", "tc4", "tc5"];
    
      
    var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");
      
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    table.classList.add('tablestyle');
    
    var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
    table.appendChild(tableBody);
   
    

    for (var i=0; i<righe; i++){
       var tr =  document.createElement('tr');
       tr.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
       tableBody.appendChild(tr);
       
       for (var j=0; j<colonne; j++){
           var td = document.createElement('td');
           td.width='75';

           if(i==0){ 
                if(j==0){ //prima casella
                    addCell(td, tr, today);
                }
                else { //prima riga
                    addCell(td, tr, providers[j-1]);
                }
           }
           else {
               if(j==0){ //prima colonna
                    addCell(td, tr, testcases[i-1]);
               }
               else {
                    addCell(td, tr, Math.floor(Math.random() * 50));
               }
            
           }
        
          
       }
    }
    myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
    
}


function addCell(td, tr, valoreCella){
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(valoreCella));
    tr.appendChild(td);
}
```

report.component.scss  (longer, but this is the part i want to work)

```
.tablestyle{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Please specific *it doesn't work*. The command `table.classList.add('tablestyle')` itself is correct and should work, unless old browser.

Comment: You `body` tag is at the wrong spot.

Comment: I have specified it.. anyway i'm not using an old browser. btw, which "body" tag??

Comment: No, you did not. *Does the class not get added? Does it throw an error? Does your style not get applied? Did you check the console for errors? Did you check the devtool-inspectior for the class attribute on the actual table?* The [`body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body) tag which holds your `onload`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made you a snippet of your code to show you that it works. Mayhap you have contradictions in your actual stylesheet.

Be aware to place the [`body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body) tag at the correct hierarchy.

```js
function addTable() {

    let colonne = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)+2;  
    let righe = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)+2;  
    
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    
    today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
    
    let providers = ["p1", "p2", "p3", "np4", "p5"];
    let testcases = ["tc1", "tc2", "tc3", "tc4", "tc5"];
    
      
    var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");
      
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    table.classList.add('tablestyle');
    
    var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
    table.appendChild(tableBody);
   
    

    for (var i=0; i<righe; i++){
       var tr =  document.createElement('tr');
       tr.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
       tableBody.appendChild(tr);
       
       for (var j=0; j<colonne; j++){
           var td = document.createElement('td');
           td.width='75';

           if(i==0){ 
                if(j==0){ //prima casella
                    addCell(td, tr, today);
                }
                else { //prima riga
                    addCell(td, tr, providers[j-1]);
                }
           }
           else {
               if(j==0){ //prima colonna
                    addCell(td, tr, testcases[i-1]);
               }
               else {
                    addCell(td, tr, Math.floor(Math.random() * 50));
               }
            
           }
        
          
       }
    }
    myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
    
}


function addCell(td, tr, valoreCella){
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(valoreCella));
    tr.appendChild(td);
}
```

```css
.tablestyle{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green
}
```

```html
<body onload="addTable()">
  <div class="block">
      <h1>STORICO DEI DATI</h1>
      <div id="myDynamicTable" class="table">
          <!--JS-->
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
table.className = 'tablestyle'
```

or

```
table.setAttribute("class", "tablestyle");
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.